# Angular - Show image from database (binary encoded)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I know this question may be a duplicate, but I've been trying for hours without success.
I have an **angular** app, it sends via form a lot of fields and one image (it's a logo)

It's saved in a mongo database, and my problem becomes when I need display the image in my web app.

When I make the /GET request it returns something like this:
[image: Response]
Of course I get a **200 OK**, and there are no problems with the request.

So, how do I transform it to a readable format by html? (*base64* maybe? Don't know if there are more solutions)

My html file:

```
<img ng-src="{{$ctrl.getLogoImg}}" />
```

My controller.js file:

```
...
vm.ReportsService.getSiteLogo( { id: vm.reportId, file: 'logo' } )
  .then( data => {
    vm.getLogoImg = data;
    console.log( 'IMG OK:' );
    console.log( data );
  } )
  .catch( err => {
    console.log( 'ERROR IMG: ', res );
  } );
```

My resource.js file:

```
...
getSiteLogo: {
  method: 'GET',
  params: { type: 'site' },
  responseType: 'arrayBuffer' // <== Not sure about this?
},
```

Maybe I need to use `transformResponse` in the resource.

I have been reading about `btoa`, `Uint8Array` and some more, without success.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the GridFs specification. This would save you time and efforts
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Sorry I can't help you with your issue, I would need to see some code...

Comment: Hello, what code do you want to see? I just need to get the image from my database and transform it to base64 or something.

The (angular) code above is all I'm using